# List active rules in Iptables

Tags: iptables

I would like to help me check the active rules in the iptables firewall.
My S.O is Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS Trusty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list the rules with the following two commands:

```
sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L
```

Those are the ones I prefer, because it can be informative to observe the packet counters, particularly when trying to debug. Also, not doing name resolution can save a lot of time.

However, there is another command, which pretty much provides the same information:

```
sudo iptables-save -c
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo iptstate -1`

Depends:

`sudo apt-get install iptstate`
`sudo modprobe ip_conntrack`

PS: I don't recommend to use `sudo iptstate`, cause sometimes, something goes wrong about Segmentation Fault.